# Set variables for strings in a list

Tags: python

Lets say I have the following list(a string variable in my script):

```
dog = lab
cat = brown
fish = wet
dog = terrier
cat = angry
fish = cooked
dog = blah
cat = soon
fish = wegetthepattern
```

I need a way to parse this list, and set these as variables based on occurence.  So in the end it would set the variables like:

```
dog1='lab'
dog2='terrier'
dog3='blah'
cat1='brown'
cat2='angry'
```

And so on.  There may be 1 time in my list that says dog, or 200, I just need a way to parse the list(which is currently a string variable I am calling to) and set these variables that I can call to later in my script.

Comment: Is it me or am I not following? *blush*

Comment: Do you really need it like that?  Why not a hash of tuples as in `{ 'dog': ('terrier','blah','lab'), 'cat': ('brown','angry') }`?

Comment: Please don't do that. Use a dict or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual answer to this is: **don't try to do it**.

You can try to achieve it, but you'll regret it. Store the words in a dict instead:

```
In [1]: s = '''dog = lab
   ...: cat = brown
   ...: fish = wet
   ...: dog = terrier
   ...: cat = angry
   ...: fish = cooked
   ...: dog = blah
   ...: cat = soon
   ...: fish = wegetthepattern'''

In [2]: from collections import defaultdict

In [3]: words = defaultdict(list)

In [4]: for pair in s.split('\n'):
   ...:    left, right = pair.split(' = ')
   ...:    words[left].append(right)
   ...:    

In [5]: words['dog']
Out[5]: ['lab', 'terrier', 'blah']
```

Comment: Cool, I get that.  On the output, is there a way to specify which append to output? like dog 2 to only get back terrier?

Comment: @user2152623 Well, you can do it the same way you always retrieve an item from a list: `words['dog'][1]` for `'terrier'`, `words['dog'][2]` for `'blah'`.

Comment: Ahh, cool. I was putting [1] inside the bracket after 'dog'.  This is exactly what I needed. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """dog = lab
cat = brown
fish = wet
dog = terrier
cat = angry
fish = cooked
dog = blah
cat = soon
fish = wegetthepattern"""

for i in s.split('\n'):
    exec(i.split()[0] + '= "' + i.split()[-1] + '"')

print(cat) # prints 'soon'
```

However you shoud avoid this.

Comment: `exec()` should be an option of last resort. It's very difficult to use securely. http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/

Comment: That's why I said "you should avoid this" ;).

Comment: @RussellBorogove From the link: "I am assuming that everybody already knows how to properly use these two, so I will not talk about security here" :)